# Duda Sobre este codigo con Recursividad

Tags: c#, recursión

Tengo Este código en c# donde hace una multiplicación utilizando recursividad. Mi duda es saber ¿cómo funciona esta parte del código y cómo logra hacer la multiplicación?. gracias.

```
 public int Mult(int x,int y)
    {

        if (y == 1)
        {
            return x;
        }
        else
        {
            return x + Mult(x, y - 1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es una multiplicación? En su forma más básica es una suma sucesiva de un mismo número, ¿estás de acuerdo? Esta función recursiva lo que hace es sumar el valor 'x' 'y' cantidad de veces... Cuando 'y' sea 1, devolverá 'x' y entonces se irán resolviendo todas las sumas, dando el resultado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El ejercicio como seguramente ya sabes, devuelve el resultado de la multiplicación entre X y Y, pero no realiza la operación de multiplicación, sino que suma X las veces Y (lo que es lo mismo).

el if solo corresponde al caso base del ejercicio, pero la parte del else es la parte que realiza esa operacion: Por ejemplo para X=3 y Y=4

[image: Corrido de la operacion]

El resultado para el ejemplo es 12. Básicamente por cada X que se sume, Y decrementa en 1.